# Rxjs websockets in angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, rxjs

let observable = Rx.Observable.create((obs: Rx.Observer) => {

```
  this.ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
  this.ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
  this.ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);

  return this.ws.close.bind(this.ws);
});
```

I am new to typescript/angular and have seen this in many tutorials on websockets but don't understand 
fully what is going on. From what i can gather the first part is binding the observer methods with the observer context to the websocket methods. This makes sense to me but i just cant work out what the return is for.
Thank you in advance and sorry if this seems abit dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Observable.create is deprecated. Use `new Observable` for that.
2. I would not recommend creating a WebSocket Observable on your own, because RxJS is already providing one. The documentation to that could be better, but here you go: https://rxjs.dev/api/webSocket/webSocket
   There was also a pretty good talk about this topic at NgSpain last year:
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEHDkAFTnzU